# ‘structure was padded due to alignment specifier’ VS warning

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings, memory-alignment

If in Visual Studio I specify alignment for a class or structure, e.g.

```
struct __declspec(align(256)) A
{
};
```

I get level 4 warning as follows ‘warning C4324: 'A': structure was padded due to alignment specifier’.
Do I specify alignment somehow incorrectly or this warning is just safe to ignore?

Comment: Generally speaking, the warnings don't affect the running of an application. So warnings are usually be ignored when programming. And for more details, I suggest you could refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501392/why-does-the-compiler-complain-about-the-alignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I specify alignment somehow incorrectly

No, although you are using a language extension. That may be unnecessary as there is a standard syntax that would be preferable:

```
struct alignas(256) A
{
};
```

> This warning is just safe to ignore?

Yes, it is safe to ignore this warning, unless you have areason to consider the padding to be a problem.

However, I recommend asking yourself: why would you need a class to be aligned when it has no members?

Comment: Class without members is just to simplify the example.